# structure packing and performance penalty

Tags: c, structure, padding, packing

```
struct struct_s { char a; int b; };
```

I want to ask how packing a structure to 1 byte aligned into 32 bit machine result into speed reduction while reading and writing it. As i know structure packing to 1 byte aligned result into store structure members one after the other and still we can read it in 1 clock cycle. so how it result into extra cycle usage with packing ?

Comment: Possible unaligned access penalties depend on the target system. On some systems it's even not possible and will result in a crash.

Comment: "and still we can read it in 1 clock cycle" this would imply that there is no penalty. This may be true or not. For some systems the compiler creates code containing multiple 8 bit read instructions and combines the value afterwards, for other systems one 32 bit read instruction is created but the MMU performs multiple reads. Or the hardware might simply allow 32bit access without any penalty.  There is no general rule for this.

Comment: so how packing result into penalty in accessing speed ?